# How to make aligned bold text without tables in Graphviz?

Tags: html, graphviz, dot

I found that aligned bold text you can create with this code. But Is there any way to do the same without creating tables?

```
digraph G {
  rankdir=LR; 
  node [shape=record, style="rounded,filled", fillcolor="#F7F7F7", fontname="Arial", fontsize=12];

  A [label=<<table border="0" cellborder="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr><td align="left"><b>Title</b></td></tr>
      <tr><td align="left">Some text</td></tr>
      </table>>];
}
```

[image]

I don't know how to place `align="left"` to the line `B [label=<<b>Title</b>>];`. For some reason alignment doesn't work with bold text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
digraph G {
  rankdir=LR; 
  node [shape=record, style="rounded,filled", fillcolor="#F7F7F7", fontname="Arial", fontsize=12];

  A [label=
    <<b>Title</b><BR ALIGN="LEFT"
    />Some text<BR ALIGN="LEFT"/>>];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

if you mean border on div here's a sample

```
.yourClass {
   border: 2px solid red;
   padding: 10px;
   border-radius: 25px;
}
```